# Hadoop: Which mapper has returned which result?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, mapper

I'm new to Hadoop. I want to run a MapReduce example and see its results with calculator mapper. That is, I want to know, each intermediate result is calculated by which mapper? Is it possible? How?

I installed Hadoop 2.9.0 (multi-node cluster).

Answer (score 0):

First we look at the sample code( I have installed HDP cluster so path may differ for .jar file)

Sample text-files as input:

> $ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /wordcount/input/

/wordcount/input/file01

/wordcount/input/file02

> $ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /wordcount/input/file01

Hello World Bye World

> $ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /wordcount/input/file02

Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop

Run the application:

> $ bin/hadoop jar
>   /usr/hdp/2.6x.x/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoo-mapreduce-examples.jar
>   wordcount /wordcount/input /wordcount/output

**Note: You don't need to write the word-count program, it is given by-default in the mapreduce folder, as I have mentioned. The code given below is just for reference to the working**

**Output:**

> $ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /wordcount/output/part-00000

Bye 1

Goodbye 1

Hadoop 2

Hello 2

World 2

Now, let's see how the mapper and reducers worked in the backend:

The WordCount application is quite straight-forward.

The **Mapper** implementation **(lines 14-26)**, via the **map method (lines 18-25)**, processes one line at a time, as provided by the specified **TextInputFormat (line 49)**. It then splits the line into tokens separated by whitespaces, via the StringTokenizer, and emits a key-value pair of < , 1>.

For the given sample input the **first map** emits:

< Hello, 1>

< World, 1>

< Bye, 1>

< World, 1>

The **second map** emits:

< Hello, 1>

< Hadoop, 1>

< Goodbye, 1>

< Hadoop, 1>

We'll learn more about the number of maps spawned for a given job, and how to control them in a fine-grained manner, a bit later in the tutorial.

WordCount also specifies a **combiner (line 46**). Hence, the output of each map is passed through the local combiner (which is same as the Reducer as per the job configuration) for local aggregation, after being sorted on the keys.

The output of the **first map**:

< Bye, 1>

< Hello, 1>

< World, 2>

The output of the **second map**:

< Goodbye, 1>

< Hadoop, 2>

< Hello, 1>

The **Reducer** implementation **(lines 28-36)**, via the reduce method (lines 29-35) just sums up the values, which are the occurence counts for each key (i.e. words in this example).

Thus the **output of the job is**:

< Bye, 1>

< Goodbye, 1>

< Hadoop, 2>

< Hello, 2>

< World, 2>

The run method specifies various facets of the job, such as the input/output paths (passed via the command line), key/value types, input/output formats etc., in the JobConf. It then calls the **JobClient.runJob (line 55)** to submit the and monitor its progress.

**Now, the word-count program which is referred here is :**

```
1.  package org.myorg;

2.  

3.  import java.io.IOException;

4.  import java.util.*;


5.  

6.  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

7.  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;

8.  import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

9.  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

10. import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

11. 

12. public class WordCount {

13. 

14.    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

15.      private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

16.      private Text word = new Text();

17. 

18.      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

19.        String line = value.toString();

20.        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

21.        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

22.          word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());

23.          output.collect(word, one);

24.        }

25.      }

26.    }

27. 

28.    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

29.      public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {


30.        int sum = 0;

31.        while (values.hasNext()) {

32.          sum += values.next().get();

33.        }

34.        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));

35.      }

36.    }

37. 

38.    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

39.      JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);

40.      conf.setJobName("wordcount");

44. 

45.      conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);

46.      conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);

47.      conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

48. 

49.      conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);

50.      conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

51. 

52.      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));

53.      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

54. 

55.      JobClient.runJob(conf);

57.    }

58. }

59.
```

Reference : [MapReduce Tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html)

Comment: Actually, I want to know 'first map' and 'second map' which nodes are? I want to find ip's node how calculated e.g 'first map'. Do you know? I'm working in Pseudo-Distributed Operation.

Comment: No. It's not possible to see which mapper is running on which node. But you can still see where the containers are allocated. Node id for the container is available in YARN web UI

Comment: Are you sure? It is important for me because I want to use the output of mappers. Please see this question [](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656448/finding-hostname-of-slave-nodes-in-hadoop-during-execution-of-running-map-reduce)

Comment: Yes. I'm sure of it.